# PHP fatal error in require_once() can n

Tags: php, fatal-error, require-once

I have a **php** file in other directory and i wanna use some data of it,but when i require_once() the file i see this error:

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Controller/UserController' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\wamp\www\newmvc\index.php on line 20

newmvc is my root
and i'm sure there is no misspelling and i have the file.

```
$Controller="user";
$param=array();
$className=ucfirst($Controller)."Controller";
$controllerfilepath="/Controller/".$className;
require_once "$controllerfilepath";
```

Comment: `/Controller` refers to the root directory "Controller" which sounds wrong unless you're indeed storing files directly under root. Perhaps take a look at the [magic constant `__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: You didnt require_once to a php file, only folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you forgot to add an extension **`.php`** for class filename:

```
$controllerfilepath="/Controller/" . $className . ".php";
```

Comment: yeah Thanks a lot.